# How can I loop and blend footage end/beginning frames in After Effects?

Tags: animation, adobe-after-effects, video

I'm trying to figure out how to do this for a couple of days now and I feel like it would probably be an easy fix.

I have a clip of a beach setting that I successfully looped with the `loopOut()` expression, but I'm having issues with the first and last frame not matching up and it's not smoothly blending to the other loop.

Obviously, I need some kind of effect or expression to help with that part, but I'm still very new to After Effects and I'm not quite sure how to go about doing it.

I've looked on the web for tutorials or explanations, but have yet to find anything useful for my problem. All I can find is how to loop an animation, which is pretty easy in itself. I need to loop FOOTAGE, not an animation.

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: Hi Sybastian. Welcome to GDSE.  If you google "AfterEffects cinemagraph tutorial" - I think you might get some useful results. These "Cinemagraph" tutorials often involve a step for editing footage into a seamless loop.  I've watched a few of these out of curiosity, never tried it yet.

Comment: Thanks very much for the tip @BillyKerr I've been looking on the web for a while but couldn't think of what some good terminology would be to even look it up. I did not go to school for motion graphics haha.

Comment: Found this video and it has exactly what i needed about 3/4 through the video. Thanks a lot @BillyKerr